# Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'props.data' as it is undefined. Whats The Error

Tags: reactjs, frontend

So I was working on a project in React and ran into a error.

I'm not sure what the error is as imo it should work just fine.

**New.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NEWCARS } from '../../Cars/NewCar'
import News from './News'
function New() {
  return (
    <div>
      {NEWCARS.map((care)=>(
        <NewCars data={care}></NewCars>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default New
```

**News.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { NEWCARS } from '../../Cars/NewCar'
function News(props) {

    const {name,price,carImage,Review} = props.data;

  return (
    <div>

        
        <div className='CarsImage'>
            <img src={carImage}></img>
        </div>
        <div className='other-info'>
            <p>
                <b>{name}</b>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>{price}</b>
            </p>
            <p>{Review}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default News
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get it work but still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the browser console for the error and [edit] your post to include that please.

Comment: `data` property on `props` is null or undefined. You could show us what is inside NEWCARS :)